Does suspension preserve the inequivalence of knots?
Let $S$ be the  suspension operator.  Let  $K1$  and  $K_2$ be  two  knots in $S^3$ which are not  equivalent. Does this  imply that their  suspensions in 4  sphere  are  not  equivalent in the sense that their  complements  are not  homeomorphic?

What do you mean by "suspension"?

He means “double cone”, I think.

The answer is “the complement of the suspension in the four-sphere is homotopy equivalent to the complement of the knot in the three-sphere”. So the fundamental group (and a bit of discussion of peripheral subgroups) distinguishes.

The title of the question is not great… you would avoid down votes (I think) if you made the title something like “Does suspension preserve the inequivalence of knots?”

@SamNead  Thanks  for  your  suggestion. I  edit the  title

@RyanBudney   By  $S(X)$  I  mean  $\frac{x\times I}{boundary}$. This  processess and its  reduced version (quotion by ${x_0}\times I$ is  frequently  used in K theory  see Hatcher Vector  bundle  and  K theory

With this version of suspension you can recover the original knot by looking at a link of the cone point.
